# Black screen after successful (?) install

Tags: boot, install, black-screen, apple

Another black screen issue here. I thought I successfully installed Elementary on a mid-2010 iMac (after editing in grub to set nomodeset). It went through the install wizard and asked for my time zone and WiFi details. Then, it asked to reboot.

On reboot, I got <strike>two ding</strike> three ring sounds (not the Mac chime, nor beeps) and a completely black screen. I can’t seem to hold down opt/alt to boot from another drive anymore.

Any ideas on how to progress? My guess is that the graphics card driver doesn’t work.

If nothing else, I’d like to at least be able to boot from USB and put OS X back on.

**2020-12-11 Update:** After rebooting by unplugging, then plugging the iMac back in, I was able to get into GRUB by hitting Esc during the Mac chime. I guess I wasn’t properly rebooting.

[Those ringing sounds from the video](https://vimeo.com/489452378) were actually ElementaryOS sounds! They’re the sound it makes when it picks up a wifi printer.

Now I have a problem with not being able to boot without recovery mode. Normal booting still takes me to a blank screen. However, if I go to GRUB during boot, pick recovery mode, then select Resume from there, it reboots in such a way that I actually get into a working instance of ElementaryOS! But if I reboot again from there, I go back to a black screen.

What’s the difference from a normal startup or reboot and a recovery mode reboot? How can I get normal startup to behave like the recovery mode reboot?

Comment: Try the shift button during boot to see if that gets you to the GRUB screen.

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately; nothing appears on the display.

Comment: Searching tells me that 2 beeps is a RAM issue?!? I'd have no idea how to proceed from here. I'll toss a vote at your question to see if it attracts attention for you.

Comment: It's more of a ring sound, rather than a beep, if that helps. And there's three of them now that I listen closely.

Comment: So, now I notice that if I leave it alone for a while, then hit the keyboard, it wakes up, then makes two ring sounds. Here’s a video: https://vimeo.com/489452378  Does this seem familiar?

Comment: Are you certain that pressing and holding the shift button doesn't get you to the GRUB menu? It can be pretty tricky to get the timing right and may take multiple attempts. In your video, you merely pressed a button on the keyboard. I'm not fluent in Mac hardware, but is there a hard power button you can press to turn it off and then turn it on again?

Comment: OK, so after rebooting by unplugging, then plugging the iMac back in, I was able to get into GRUB by hitting Esc during the Mac chime. Thanks for your suggestion of making sure I was hard rebooting!

Those ringing sounds from the video were actually ElementaryOS sounds! They’re the sound it makes when it picks up a wifi printer. Now I have a problem with not being able to boot without recovery mode. I’ll add it to the question!

Comment: You're really supposed to make each question separately. However, recovery mode means it doesn't load everything and you're able to use it to run commands from a terminal to fix the situation. Add 'nomodeset' to GRUB - a search engine will explain it. You should be able to do it during boot, at the GRUB screen, by pressing F6 or whatever (I forget at the moment) is the 'advanced' option.

Comment: I believe the ring sounds are the system finding your printer automatically.